# Simple query in MySQL procedure nested inside while loop won't work

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am a newie with stored procedures, and I have a question about them with MySQL and their use inside while loops, something like a query_1 > while_loop > query_2. Very clear and simple.

I have this example with a random table, with users for example:

```
// FIRST QUERY
$result_1 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM user");
if($result_1){
    while ($row_1 = $result_1->fetch_object()){
        $id_1 = $row_1->id;
        echo "<b>id_1: ".$id_1."</b><br />";
        // SECOND QUERY
        $result_2 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM user");
        if($result_2){
            while ($row_2 = $result_2->fetch_object()){
                $id_2 = $row_2->id;
                echo "id_2: ".$id_2."<br />";
            }
            $result_2->close();
            $connection->next_result();
        }
    }
    $result_1->close();
    $connection->next_result();
}
```

It works. Then I store the queries in procedures, and make the calls like this:

```
$result_1 = $connection->query("CALL test_procedure()");
$result_2 = $connection->query("CALL test_procedure()");
```

Identical procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure()
BEGIN
SELECT * from user;
END
```

If i put both queries in stored procedures, only the first query works, and the second fails. If I put in a stored procedure only the second, everything is OK, but the first has to be in the PHP. And I can't figure why… Anyone knows?

EDIT: this are the results:

Both queries with the SQL in the PHP:

```
$result_1 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM user");
$result_2 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM user");
```

Or with the second query in a stored procedure:

```
$result_1 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM user");
$result_2 = $connection->query("CALL x_test()");
```

The result is:

```
id_1: 1
id_2: 1
id_2: 2
id_2: 3
id_2: 4
id_2: 5
id_1: 2
id_2: 1
id_2: 2
id_2: 3
id_2: 4
id_2: 5
id_1: 3
id_2: 1
id_2: 2
id_2: 3
id_2: 4
id_2: 5
etc.
```

But with the first query in a stored procedure and the second with the SQL in the PHP:

```
$result_1 = $connection->query("CALL x_test()");
$result_2 = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM user");
```

Or with both queries in stored procedures

```
$result_1 = $connection->query("CALL x_test()");
$result_2 = $connection->query("CALL x_test()");
```

The result is:

```
id_1: 1
id_1: 2
id_1: 3
etc.
```

And I don't know why!

Comment: Php isn't my strongest area, but it sounds to me like the problem isn't the stored procedure; it's that you are no longer calling the second query for every resulting row from the first one. ..unless when you said "make the calls like this" you mean replacing the existing calls, not executing them both once at the start.

Comment: What API are you using: PDO, mysqli, or other? Also, what do you mean *the second fails*? Does an error/exception raise? Or undesired result like an empty *$result_2*? Also, is your example simplified as there is an alternative without nested `while` looping or querying twice.

Comment: I am using mysqli. I will edit the question with the results, is easy to test it.

Comment: @Uueerdo, I make the calls inside the main structure. It is very strange, because it should work!